# Best way to effectively disconnect a test device from eclipse

Tags: android

I am new to android development and I have been having problems with disconnecting my smartphone from my ubuntu development platform running Eclipse.  When I initially plug my phone in with the usb, the system sees it and all is well.  However, if I disconnect it from the system and then plug it back in, the system does not recognize it.  I have been rebooting the system everytime it does this.  Is there a way to "safely" unplug the phone without having to reboot? Should I close Eclipse?  Do I need to "unmount" the phone or is there a way to "restart" the android.rules in the rules.d folder?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean logcat loses its connection?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and simply turning Usb Debugging off, then back on solved the situation -every time-.

After a while, when I set the default connectivity to Charge only, the problem went away.

These are just workarounds based on my experience, but might help you.